# python : afectation sometimes ignored

Tags: python, events, socket.io, global-variables

I've used python on a few projects, but always rather basic stuff.
This time, I'm writting a piece of code to interact with a web server using socketIO (another company is doing the website, I "just" have to send/receive the messages on the robot side).

The problem is that, inside an event function, I change a global variable : sometimes everything seems fine, but sometimes the variable isn't changed (in that case, even if printing it from inside the fuction, it dispalays the old value)

```
import socketio
import time
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='test_log.log',level=logging.DEBUG,\
      format='%(asctime)s -- %(name)s -- %(levelname)s -- %(message)s')

sio = socketio.Client()

robot_status='IDLE'
start_time_of_mission=time.time()

@sio.event(namespace='/foo')
def connect(logger=True, engineio_logger=True):
    print('connection established')
    while (1==1):
        dic={'battery': {'level':0}, 'location':{'lat':43.684036, 'lng':7.202622}, 'status':robot_status, 'timestamp':int(1000*time.time())}
        print (dic)
        sio.emit('foo.state',dic,  namespace='/foo')
        print('message sent')
        time.sleep(5)

@sio.on('foo.goto',namespace='/foo')
def on_message(data):
    poi=data['poi'];
    print('I received goto message : poi=', poi)
    global robot_status
    global start_time_of_mission
    if(robot_status!='IDLE'):
        dic={'error': True, 'message':'the robot is busy'}
        print('ERROR : the robot can\'t accept POI because it is busy')
        return dic
    elif(poi=="somewhere"):
        #return "OK"
        robot_status='GOING_TO_DESTINATION'
        start_time_of_mission=time.time()
        dic={'OK': True}
        print('POI accepted')
        print(robot_status)
        return dic
    else:
        #return "ERROR"
        dic={'error': True, 'message':'unknown destination'}
        print('ERROR : unknown POI')
        return dic


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

sio.connect('http://my_testing_server.com', headers={}, transports=['websocket'], namespaces=['/foo'])
while (True):
    if (time.time()>start_time_of_mission+60):  #for testing purpose, it takes always 1 minute to reach destination
        robot_status='IDLE'
sio.wait()
```

Usually, the robot_status is IDLE.
From the test website, I can send a "foo.goto" message with content {'poi' : 'somewhere'}. (nb : 'somewhere' is for now really the string 'somwhere').
When receiving this message when in IDLE state, we are supposed to go to GOING_TO_DESTINATION state.
When all goes OK (80% of the time), I get the following output :

```
I received goto message : poi= somewhere
POI accepted
GOING_TO_DESTINATION
```

And then, I start publishing that I'm in GOING_TO_DESTINATION status

However, sometimes (maybe 20% of the time), I get:

```
I received goto message : poi= somewhere
POI accepted
IDLE
```

And then, I keep publishing that i'm in IDLE state.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?
I would guess it has someting to do with the concurency (using events) and theway I use global variables, but I have no idea what the issue is exactly.

Thanks a lot in advance

Felix

Comment: Is there another thread assigning `IDLE` to `robot_status`?

Comment: I posted the complete code.
The only place were we asign 'IDLE' to robot_status is at the very end of the code, in the while loop.
I think this might indeed cause some problems depending what is really happening.
If the event handler acts as an interrupt, then it don't explains the problem. If it acts as another thread, then it might be the problem)

Comment: I also have a feeling it's related to that loop. Add `print("idling")` to the loop to see if it's running at the same time.

Comment: Also put `time.sleep(1)` in the loop so you don't get millions of prints.

Comment: before adding the time.sleep, I got the terminal so filed with idling that I couldn't see anything else.
When adding it, I see idling beween each event (but it is very unlikely to get one in beween the enven handling, even in the case that it is possible.

Comment: Unless you have a mutex preventing it, they can happen in between.

Comment: for now, I haven't seen any new bugged case.
I also tried adding the additional condition that I put the state to IDLE only if we are in GOING_TO_DESTINATION : I haven't observed any bug either.
I think by adding it, the problem is probably solved.
Thanks a lot to pointing to me that it might be a concurreny problem istead of a python problem!

Comment: The sleep just makes it less likely, since the loop isn't running as often. It could still happen.